# How to retrieve only immediate child object from a JSON response using Spring 5

Tags: json, spring, rest, spring-boot, microservices

I have build a small microservice using SpringBoot2 and Spring 5 which has a REST service exposed (HTTP GET Method) and which internally consumes another REST GET service (third party API). Using Postman when I call my service (GET), then I get a JSON response but the problem is I get a complete whole object in response like below :-

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Open Catalogue",
        "subcategories": [
            {
                "id": "106",
                **"name": "Components",**
                "subcategories": [
                    {
                        "id": "816",
                        "name": "Power Supplies",
                        "subcategories": [
                            {
                                "id": "814",
                                "name": "Rechargeable Batteries",
                                "subcategories": [],
                                "sample": {
                                    "empty": true,
                                    "lazy": false,
                                    "async": false
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "id": "829",
                                "name": "Battery Chargers",
                                "subcategories": [],
                                "samples": {
                                    "empty": true,
                                    "lazy": false,
                                    "async": false

                                }
                            },
```

My service URL used in post man is like this :-
**http://localhost:8080/test-search?searchKey=ball**
So my requirement is whenever a user consume this service by a sub-category name then only that sub-category details along with its immediate child details should be returned and not the child of child.
Here searchKey in URL is nothing but a free text to search for a sub-category. For instance when I say :-
**http://localhost:8080/test-search?searchKey=Components**

then only below details should be returned like this :-

```
                "id": "106",
                "name": "Components",
                "subcategories": [
                    {
                        "id": "816",
                        "name": "Power Supplies",
```

Response should not have sub-categories of Power Supplies i.e. "subcategories": [  "id": "814",
                                "name": "Rechargeable Batteries",

Is there any efficient way to do the filtering while preparing the JSON response or first fetch whole object and then start filtering?

Please advise, thank you

Comment: Could you please add some real code?

Comment: If you json is mapped to an object, then your subcategories are probably a `List`.  So to retrieve the first category only, check for the `list.size() > 1`, then return `list.get(0).getId()` and `list.get(0).getName()`. But you need to give some more informations about how did you implement this.